# Show that $2n+1$ is a factor of the sum of positive odd powers of the first $2n$ integers

Tags: number-theory, summation, divisibility

This question comes from a high school math book. We are currently learning about binomial coefficients and combinatorial proofs, which we should use for this according to our teacher, but I don't see how that can be used for this particular problem.

The question is:

> Show that for all $a,n \in \mathbb{N}$, $2a+1$ is a factor of the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{2a} i^{2n+1}$.

I know that for $n=0$, this follows from the summation formula, which is $\frac{2a(2a+1)}{2} = a(2a+1)$. But I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint.* $i^{2n+1}+(2a+1-i)^{2n+1}\equiv 0\pmod{2a+1}$ since we are considering odd powers. Pair the summands up, and the conclusion should follow.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** 1: use the fact that $(x+y) | (x^{2k+1}+y^{2k+1})$.

**Hint** 2: try grouping the numbers so you get the factor you are looking for.